# ListView, SimpleCursorAdapter или как записать строку в ListView

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview, cursor

Как вставить строку в адаптер `ListView`?

```
Cursor getPositions() {
     return mDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+ TABLE + " WHERE _id = 0", null);
}
```

На выходе в `ListView` находится только первое значение. Цикл работает, я так понимаю проблема в адаптере, который по всей видимости не предназначен для записи строки в виде столбца в `ListView`?

```
  cursor = DB.getPositions();
  String[] from = new String[cursor.getColumnCount()]; // создаём массив, размерность которого равна количеству столбцов.
  for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getColumnCount(); i++) { 
       from [i] = "P" + i; // в массив заносим названия столбцов, получается P1, P2, P3 и т.д.
       }
  scAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.simple_item, cursor, from, new int[] {android.R.id.text1}, 0); //объявляем адаптер и вносим туда известные нам названия столбцов.
  listview.setAdapter(scAdapter);
```

Comment: *который по всей видимости не предназначен для записи строки в виде столбца* - можно подробнее, что вы имеет ввиду?

Comment: Из таблицы в SQLite я беру строку с _id = 0, записываю в Cursor. Данные в Cursor (поэлементно) мне необходимо записать в ListView, когда я курсором считываю данные построчно в пределах одного столбца таблицы я вижу нужную мне картину, но когда я хочу считать данные по столбцам в пределах одной строки я получаю самый первый элемент массива. Количество записей в Cursor соответствует количеству элементов в массиве from и соответствует количеству столбцов. Массив from содержит названия столбцов моей таблицы в SQLite.

Comment: Вам нужно значение каждого столбца одной строки из БД вывести в ListView как отдельный айтем? "горизонтальную" запись из БД отобразить, как "вертикальный" список, то есть значение из столбца Р1 в первой позиции списка, Р2 во второй и тд? или раскройте свою проблему подробнее

Comment: Именно так, как вы и написали.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пытался найти решение чисто через Cursor, честно говоря не смог.

```
   cursor = DB.getPositions();
   List<String>lt = new ArrayList<String>();
   String ad = null;
   cursor.moveToFirst();
       for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getColumnCount(); i++) {
           ad = cursor.getString(i);
           lt.add(ad);
       }
       arAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),R.layout.simple_item, lt);
       listview.setAdapter(arAdapter);
```